# Running MATLAB system command in background with stdout

Tags: matlab, system, stdout

I'm using MATLAB and calling an .exe via the system command.

```
[status,cmdout] = system(command_s);
```

where `command_s` is a command string that is formatted earlier in my script to pass all the desired options to the .exe. The .exe would normally write to a .csv file via the `>` redirection operator in Windows/DOS. Instead, this output is going to `cmdout` where I use it later in the MATLAB script. It is working correctly and as expected. I'm doing it this way so that the process just uses memory and does not write a very large file to the disk, which would then have to be read from the disk and then deleted after I'm done with it. In the end, it saves a .mat file that's usually in hundreds of KB instead of 10s/100s of MBs as the .csv file would be (some unneeded data is thrown out in the end).

The issue I'm having is since I'm dealing with large files, the executable can take a significant amount of time. I typically have to wait about 2 minutes after executing this command. In the meantime, I have no feedback to know it is progressing and that my system hasn't froze. I know I could add the `&` symbol to the end of my string, `command_s`, and run MATLAB code while this is running in the background (or asynchronously as some would say), but that brings up an external window AND makes `cmdout` empty - so I cannot use the output - forcing me to sit there for 2 minutes wondering each time it executes.

Is there any way to run in the background AND get the stdout from the command?

Comment: NOTE: I created a workaround where I use a MATLAB timer object and use an interrupt to generate messages while the command is running. Not ideal, but it's working "good enough" at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try system(command_s,'-echo')?